# Selenium XPath exception c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I've created an XPath to click on the 'bag' icon at the top right-hand corner of the page once I've selected the shoe size and added to the bag. I've created an XPath for this but it seems to throw an exception when this is run:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='bagicon']")).Click();
```

> http://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air-max-97-trainers-in-gold-884421-700/prd/9059998?clr=gold&SearchQuery=nike%20trainers&gridcolumn=1&gridrow=1&gridsize=4&pge=1&pgesize=72&totalstyles=512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Xpath as below

```
//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']
```